# Website has backdoor PHP/Small.m how to remove?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, security

I've one website which is affected by backdoor PHP/Small.m , how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to find the file and remove it. You can just delete it via FTP or SSH.  Alternatively, you can set it to CHMOD 000 permissions, which will be helpful if there's a system that's trying to re-publish the file in the same location.

But you'll also want to make sure that there are no other files on the server that are also affected - you'll want to do a scan of the system.

If you have the Git version control system installed and running for the site, check to see if there are any uncommited files.  But make sure to check media directories - files can sometimes hide out there and will go undetected, as they are not detected via git due to a gitignore file.

You will also want to see if you can track down how the file was injected into the site.  Often it's an insecure WordPress plugin, or some directory that is open to the world with 777 permissions.

The vulnerability may be contained in the mySQL database - so you'll want to check there as well.

One other option: do a backup of the (infected) site and run a difference comparison between it and a clean non-hacked version of the site.  This will likely help you find out what's been added (or deleted).

I hope this helps!